# Unable to send current city name to the API

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-mvvm

I am fetching weather data from an API. The problem that I am facing is when I get the cityName in textView from the current locations and then I have to send that cityName to the API so I can get the temperature of that city. But I am unable to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

**HomeRepositery**

```
suspend fun getWeatherDataFromApi(cityName : String,appid : String) =
       weatherServiceApi.getchWeatherData(cityName, appid)
```

> **HomeViewModel**

```
val weatherData: MutableLiveData<Resource<WeatherDataClass>> = MutableLiveData()

        init {
            getWeatherDataFromRepo("" ,"appid")
        }
        //here we make a network  response
        fun getWeatherDataFromRepo(cityName: String, appId: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
                weatherData.postValue(Resource.Loading())
                val response = homeRepositery.getWeatherDataFromApi(cityName, appId)
                weatherData.postValue(handleWeatherResponseData(response))
        }
```

> **Fragment**

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getLocation() {
       
        val fusedLocationProviderClient =
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())
       
        val locationRequest = LocationRequest().setInterval(100000).setFastestInterval(100000)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            object : LocationCallback() {
                override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                    super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
                    for (location in locationResult.locations) {


                        latTextView.text = location.latitude.toString()

                        lngTextView.text = location.longitude.toString()
                        
                        tv_cityName.text = getCityName(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                        onObserveLiveData()
                    }
                    // Few more things we can do here:
                    // For example: Update the location of user on server
                }

            },
            Looper.myLooper()
        )
    }

    private fun onObserveLiveData() {
        viewModel.weatherData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { response ->
            when (response) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    response.data?.let { weatherResponse ->

                        tv_humidity.text = weatherResponse.main.humidity.toString()
                        tv_weather.text = weatherResponse.clouds.all.toString()
                        tv_temp.text = weatherResponse.main.temp.toString()

                    }
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    response.message?.let {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            "THeir is am error in fetching",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        requireContext(),
                        "Is in Loading state so please wait foe while!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        })
    }
```